# Откуда берутся лишние пробелы при использовании np.array и np.dot в списках на выходе?

Tags: python, массивы, numpy

Учусь по книге ["Грокаем глубокое обучение" Траск Э.](https://habr.com/ru/company/piter/blog/464509/). В одной из первых глав авторами был предложен нижеследующий код. При его исполнении в списках появляются лишние пробелы.

Не могу понять, откуда берутся эти лишние пробелы?

```
import numpy as np
#веса входные
ih_wgt = np.array([
    [0.1, 0.2, -0.1],
    [-0.1, 0.1, 0.9],
    [0.1, 0.4, 0.1]]).T

#веса скрытого слоя
hp_wgt = np.array([
    [0.3, 1.1, -0.3],
    [0.1, 0.2, 0.0],
    [0.0, 1.3, 0.1]]).T

weights = [ih_wgt, hp_wgt]


def neural_network(input, weights):
    hid = input.dot(weights[0])
    pred = hid.dot(weights[1])
    return pred


toes = np.array([8.5, 9.5, 9.9, 9.0])
wlrec = np.array([0.65, 0.8, 0.8, 0.9])
nfans = np.array([1.2, 1.3, 0.5, 1.0])

number = 0

for i in range(len(toes)):
    input = np.array([toes[number], wlrec[number], nfans[number]])
    pred = neural_network(input, weights)
    print(pred)
    number += 1
#На выходе получается:
[0.2135 0.145  0.5065]
[0.204 0.158 0.53 ]
[-0.584  0.018 -0.462]
[-0.015  0.116  0.253]
```

Comment: В списках нет ни пробелов, ни скобок - это просто текстовое представление данных. В данном случае имеют значение только числа.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

В Python при выводе объекта на печать при помощи функции [print(*objects, sep=' ', end='\n', file=sys.stdout, flush=False)](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#print) ко всем выводимым объектам применяется метод `obj.__str__()`, что и является причиной появления пробелов в вашем случае.

Воспроизведение:

```
In [91]: toes
Out[91]: array([8.5, 9.5, 9.9, 9. ])

In [92]: str(toes)
Out[92]: '[8.5 9.5 9.9 9. ]'

In [93]: toes.__str__()
Out[93]: '[8.5 9.5 9.9 9. ]'

In [94]: print(toes)
[8.5 9.5 9.9 9. ]
```

PS данные пробелы появляются только при выводе на печать (или при вызове методов/функций: `np_obj.__str__()`, `str(np_obj)`, etc.) - исходные данные остаются неизменными